# Java 1.5 Command Line Password Masking

Tags: java, command-line, passwords

All,

Our server is running Java 1.5 and I am having difficulty trying to mask user input from the command line. I am executing a jar file (java -jar my.jar) and am working through command line prompts via printlns. I cannot use Java Console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Unix system? You could try running the system program `stty` with argument `-echo` before reading the program and the program `stty echo` afterwards.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("stty", "-echo");
pb.start().waitFor();
// Read the password here
pb = new ProcessBuilder("stty", "echo");
pb.start().waitFor();
```

Note that I have not tried this! Some `stty` programs are happy with it and some aren't (those that aren't need their *stdin* to come from `/dev/tty` to work right...)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to use Java 6's [Console](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) readPassword() method. Since you mentioned that you are using Java 5, that is not an option. A lot of Java 6 utilities have been backported to Java 5. I have not found anyone who has done it for this class though.

This site has a good article on how to do it using Java 5. http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005/. Basically they wrap System.in with an InputStreamReader and read a line.

Comment: The article you're linking to (and the approach you mention) is how to read from a command line, not how to mask the input on the console as the question is looking for. Based on the OP, I imagine he already knows how to read values from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask/

**edit** now that I re-read that, I think their command-line "solution" is really stupid. What we've got in our application is an auxiliary program to do that, one that understands how to mask input according to the OS (Linux, Windows, whatever). The Java code listens for commands on a socket, and the front-end password reader gets the password and anything else needed, then sends commands to the Java code.

Comment: Yea I read that article and wasn't impressed with it. I am going to switch it out to prompt via shell script if there isn't a decent solution.