# Masking password in Java CLI application

Tags: java, command-line, passwords, mask

I've made this little ATM application in Java (CLI) and in the beginning I want to have "Code: " and then the user should enter it, and in my Java application it should say something like String(or int?) code = 1234; and if that works then proceed, if not wrong, try again, if faulty 3 times, stop app.

How would something like that look? I've been googling for hours now after masked passwords and tried different types of code without any luck. I just want something simple that converts the string to asterisk.

Currently my password masking looks like this:

```
java.io.Console cons;
char[] passwd;

if ((cons = System.console()) != null && (passwd = cons.readPassword("[%s]", "Code:")) != null)
```

However I'm not able (don't know) how to set a password in the code.

Comment: What do you have currently that is not working?

Comment: I edited my first post with the code I'm currently using.

Comment: Regarding "I've been googling for hours"... Then you probably don't know how to use Google. The first search result for "java command line password masking" is just what you need.

Comment: I've been looking at the first ones coming up but they didn't help me because I obviously didn't understand them correctly.

Comment: and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398269/java-1-5-command-line-password-masking) is an SO answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `readPassword` method of class `java.io.Console`.

The [API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) of class `Console` has an example that shows how to read a password from the console window without echoing it in plaintext.

*edit*

Michael, this code is to let a user enter a keyword in the console window without displaying it. After the user has done that, the password is stored in the variable `passwd`. It seems that what you really want is something completely different: you have some other program that asks for a password, and you want your program to enter that password automatically.

If that is indeed what you want to do, then you don't need to use class `Console`. You could try using class `java.awt.Robot` to enter keystrokes in another application (but I'm not sure that it would work with a console window - try it out).

Comment: That's what I'm currently using but how do I set a password with it?

Comment: @Michael: Describe what you mean by "set a password with it." From your example, you have the `char[] passwd` variable which will be filled with the password text. What more do you want? *Where* do you want to "set" the password?

Comment: Well if I put char[somepassword] passwd;
It just wont run, the "somepassword" line becomes underscored in red.
I tried with char[] passwd = somepassword; and char['p'] passwd; but noone of it works.

Comment: Things like `char[somepassword] passwd;` and `char['p'] passwd;` are not valid Java code. What do you want to accomplish with that?

Comment: I want to set a password in my code that I can later input in the console to be able to use the application.

Answer (score 0):

This site has an example of pretty much exactly what you are trying to do: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

To be thorough, [here](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=43) are [two](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/ConsolereadPasswordStringfmtObjectargs.htm) more links to similar tutorials.

Do they answer your question?

Based on your comments, perhaps you do not understand Java syntax exactly.

You cannot write:

```
char["mypassword"] passwd;
```

I think you mean instead:

```
String str = "mypassword";
char[] passwd = str.toCharArray();
```

---

**Update**

Try this code:

```
Console c = System.console();
if (c == null) {
    System.err.println("No console.");
    System.exit(1);
}

char [] passwd = c.readPassword("Enter your password: ");

c.println("Password is:");
c.println(new String(passwd));
```

Comment: Well if I try something like:

`String str = "mypassword";

char[] passwd = str.toCharArray();
   
if ((cons = System.console()) != null && (passwd = cons.readPassword("[%s]", "Code: ")) != null)

{
  ......mycode
}`

The application works, but the password doesn't. I'm still able to log into the app with a blank password.

Comment: @Michael: See my update - does that work? Does it print out the password correctly?

Comment: @Michael: C'mon now, of course you need the appropriate `import java.io.Console;` line. And some class with `public static void main(...)`, etc. (:

Comment: @Michael: or just replace `Console` with `java.io.Console`, as in your example code in your original question.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this sun Java [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask/)... it highlights a number of different ways to do it.

Specifically it shows how to use AWT's `TextField` class with the `setEchoChar()` method, as well as a method that runs a separate thread to remove and replace typed characters in console applications.

Comment: The first thing that came up in my mind, but you were faster :) Yeah, that's the way to do it prior Java 6.

Comment: @Michael, read more carefully, there is a section "Command-Line Input Masking"

Comment: just read the bit about command line... but the article is still valid... it highlights some interesting ways to do it

Comment: Not only does this answer itself miss the point of the question, but the link to the article that "highlights a number of different ways to do it" is dead. Always extract information relevant to the answer rather than just linking to an article.